# Downgrade Safari webdriver extension version to 2.38

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, protractor, safari-extension, safaridriver

There is a known issue with the Safari WebDrier extension version 2.45 working with Protractor ([found here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2111)), i need to downgrade to 2.38 to work with my protractor tests, any idea how i can do this?

i managed to locate the 2.38 extension .jar file ([found here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.38.0)), i extracted the jar file and located the .safariextz file but when i installed using that it just installed 2.45 anyway instead of 2.38

I am completely new to Mac so that's why i don't know, i cant seem to find anything about downgrading safari extensions